# Is there any performance benefit to using $(this) vs caching selector to a variable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is $(this) the same as caching a selector? Does $(this) search the DOM everytime?

For example:

```
$('#selector').on('click', function() {
    $(this).method();
    $(this).method1();
    $(this).method2();

    //OR

    var selector = $('#selector');

    selector.method();
    selector.method1();
    selector.method2();

}
```

Comment: in the first example you create 3 jquery objects, in the second, just one

Comment: I think what you really mean is this 
`var $this = $(this);
  $this.method();
  $this.method1();
  $this.method2();

  //This is another jQuery obj
  var $selector = $('#selector') // You have already the selector on $this`

Answer (score 7):

Defining `$(this)` doesn't require a DOM search, but it does create a new object in memory. In your example, the difference in performance might be negligible, but it's still good practice to use one object instead of creating three identical ones. I often see `var $this = $(this)` -- adding that one line saves both memory and typing, and it's clear to anyone reading your code what `$this` is.

Comment: Is using the $ for `var $this` just to specify the variable is a jQuery object?

Comment: Yep. It's a common practice (but by no means required) to start names for variables containing jquery objects with a `$`.

Answer (score 1):

In this context

```
$('#selector').on('click', function() {
  $(this).method();
  $(this).method1();
  $(this).method2();
});
```

'this' is a local variable which refers to the DOM element. So to answer your questions, this is not doing a 'dom'query every single time. You are however calling $(this) several times, which is passing the 'this' DOM element to the jquery constructor and giving you a jquery object. A more optimal way to do this would be as follows:

```
$('#selector').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.method();
  $this.method1();
  $this.method2();
});
```

The second method

```
$('#selector').on('click', function() {
  var selector = $("#selector");
  selector.method();
  selector.method1();
  selector.method2();
});
```

would be a little more expensive, since $("#selector") would end up doing a DOM query.

Comment: Is using the $ for $this just to specify the variable is a jQuery object?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Just to distinguish it from a regular javascript variable.